# Sudoers Permissions - User in Multiple Groups

Tags: permissions, sudo

I want to learn to rules pertaining to the effective permissions assigned to a certain user. I've come across this paragraph in Ubuntu's sudoers man page and also in numerous posts here:

> The `sudoers` file is read in one pass so when multiple entries match for a user, they are applied in order. Where there are conflicting values, the last match is used (which is not necessarily the most specific match).

However, let me show you two experiments I've done that show otherwise (on an Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS) :

I have created the user `test_sudo`, the groups `test1` and `test2` and added `test_sudo` to both groups. My `sudoers` file before each experiment is the default one.

**First Experiment:** I've inserted the following lines to my sudoers file these lines:

```
%test1 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
%test2 ALL=(ALL) /usr/bin/git
```

After the addition, I was able to `sudo` any command I wished without entering password (including `git`).

**Second Experiment:** I've inserted the following lines to my `sudoers` file:

```
%test2 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
%test2 ALL=(ALL) /usr/bin/git
```

After the addition, I was able to `sudo` any command without password, **except** `git`, which required a password.

This brings me to ask, what is the ordered logical set of rules predetermining what will be the effective permission of a user (there must be one as the calculation of the effective permissions is done by code obviously)?

Obviously the aforementioned quote from Ubuntu's documentation is insufficient to describe the mechanism.

Comment: The aforementioned quote is insufficient, but did you read the whole `man 5 sudoers` page? It is very long. In the end, it's open source and you can always look into the code to see how it is supposed to operate.

Comment: I cannot reproduce on an Ubuntu 22.04 container (sudo `1.9 9-1ubuntu2.4`). With the config in the first experiment, the test user I made is asked for a password with `sudo git`.

Comment: The condition `%test2 ... /usr/bin/git` is a more specific match for  `sudo git`, so it is preferred. I agree with @NikitaKipriyanov , the One True Document is the source. `apt source sudo`

Comment: @waltinator That was my suspicion - it seems that the commands permitted for a user are aggregated, and then for each command the most restrictive permission is the effective one. However, it is different from what is mention in the documents...
I really would like to get to the bottom of the functionality

Comment: You mention creating a user `test_sudo` and the groups `test1` and `test2`, but you haven't said which groups the user is a member of.  Please edit the question to mention this (and whether the group membership changed before each of your experiments).  Also, after each change you make to the sudo configuration file, for repeatable results it's best to log out of the `test_sudo` account and log back in.

Comment: @SottoVoce You are correct, sorry for that. I've edited the question...

Comment: @G.Bar looks good, but did you log out of test_sudo and back in after you edited your sudoers file for Experiment 2 (before you tried invoking the commands)?

Comment: @SottoVoce I did, but I can verify that by redoing the experiment

Comment: @G.Bar Check for other entries in include files (often found in an `/etc/sudoers.d` directory) that could be influencing sudo's configuration for your test user.  Also, it's a **very** good idea to keep a separate session running that has root privileges and edit the sudo configuration in that session.  If you make a typo in a sudo config file and save the change to disk, you'll lose the ability to use sudo to become root and fix the error.  A session that already has root privileges will be able to revert the change.